# UILabel text breaks single word by character when it should break by word

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I have this `xib` file which has 3 labels.
I need the labels to act as a table header, which means the labels `line` property is set to `0` and the `line break` property set to `word wrap`.

This sounds promising, but it breaks single words by character and if the label has more than one word it shows the first word only.

I have tried anything I can think about, and am trying to stay in the XCODE editor and write code as little as possible.

**Edit**: The behaviour I'm aiming at is this:
If it's a single word and won't fit inside the designated area: make the text smaller.
If it's more than one word, break the phrase but **never** break a word by character.

Here's an image of my `xib` file.

[image: My xib]

As you can see, the single word (encyclopedia) is broken into 2 lines.

Comment: How is it supposed to wrap by word if it's only one word?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I want it to just shrink the text in that case.

Comment: Truncation would look better that an unhyphenated word wrapped onto two lines.

Answer (score 1):

It's acting as expected: "Wrapping occurs at word boundaries, unless the word itself doesn’t fit on a single line." ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslinebreakmode?language=objc))